# Simplest way to Import a shared python script relative to the current script

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import one python script from another.  I have a few common functions defined in one script and then lots of other scripts that want to import those functions.  No classes, just functions.

The importing script needs to import from a relative path e.g.  `../../SharedScripts/python/common.py`

I then a have a few functions `def f1(...)` defined which I will call.

I found the imp module which seemed to be the right thing to use but I was unable to figure out the exact syntax that would work for my example.

Can someone suggest the correct code to use or the simplest approach if imp is not the right module?

**SOLUTION** from the answers below I was able to get this working...

```
projectKey = 'THOR'

# load the shared script relative to this script
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../../SharedScripts/python')
import jira

jira.CheckJiraCommitMessage(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], projectKey)
```

Where I had an empty `__init__.py` and a `jira.py` in the `SharedScripts/python` directory with plain function definitions.

Comment: There is a better way to get the absolute path: `os.path.abspath` (see my post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not adding `../../SharedScripts/python/` to the python path? Then you could use `common.py` like any other module:

```
import common
common.f1()
```

You can alternate the Python path through the system variable `PYTHONPATH` or by manipulating it directly from python: `sys.path.append("../../SharedScripts/python/")`

*Please notice that it is probably wiser to work with absolute pathes... (The current directory of the app could change)*

To get the absolute path could can call use the function `os.path.abspath`: `os.path.abspath('../../SharedScripts/python/')`

Comment: Thanks this sounds reasonable but isn't working at the moment, see comments under thesamet's post.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to add the directory to the Python path before doing the import.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.path.append('../../SharedScripts/python')
import common
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but just got an unknown module error.  I have an empty <pre>__init__.py</pre> in python directory.  The common.py just has some def func1() definitions.  Could it be a relative path issue, perhaps the current directory is not the script location?

Comment: call `os.getcwd()` to know your current folder

Comment: @MikeQ you thank me but reward thesamet... life is unfair :-p

Comment: @gecco, fair point, i didn't realise yours was the other answer :)